# Device Farm test upload status sits in "INITIALIZED" status forever

Tags: aws-device-farm

I'm using AWS CLI to upload my android app and the tests.zip file to device farm. My test project type is Appium + Java + TestNG.

I'm able to upload the android app successfully, but while trying to upload the "tests.zip" the upload status shows INITIALIZED for ever, even though the upload is completed successfully.(using curl command)

I'm not able to proceed with my automated tests because of this issue. Any clue/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Below is the code snippet that I've been trying with so far and its output.

```
TEST_UPLOAD_RESPONSE=$(aws devicefarm create-upload --project-arn $DEVICE_FARM_PROJECT_ARN --name "zip-with-dependencies.zip" --type "APPIUM_JAVA_TESTNG_TEST_PACKAGE" --region "us-west-2" --output "json")
ANDROID_TEST_ARN=$(echo $TEST_UPLOAD_RESPONSE | jq '.upload.arn' | tr -d \")
TEST_PRESIGNED_URL=$(echo $TEST_UPLOAD_RESPONSE | jq '.upload.url' | tr -d \")
echo "Test upload url is :$TEST_PRESIGNED_URL"
echo "Test upload arn is :$ANDROID_TEST_ARN"

curl -T ./target/zip-with-dependencies.zip $APP_PRESIGNED_URL
sleep 5s
TEST_UPLOAD_STATUS=""
while [ "$TEST_UPLOAD_STATUS" != "SUCCEEDED" ]
do
  TEST_UPLOAD_STATUS=$(aws devicefarm get-upload --arn $ANDROID_TEST_ARN --query upload.status)
  TEST_UPLOAD_STATUS=$(echo $TEST_UPLOAD_STATUS | tr -d \")
  echo "Test upload status : $TEST_UPLOAD_STATUS"
done
```

> App upload url is :https://prod-us-west-2-uploads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A949397191675%3Aproject%3Acd2fdd09-4c62-42f4-8e27-bde987554d70/uploads/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A949397191675%3Aupload%3Acd2fdd09-4c62-42f4-8e27-bde987554d70/22d28644-4c01-4b82-939c-8e39ee5a268e/zip-with-dependencies.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190525T230634Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJSORV74ENYFBITRQ%2F20190525%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=4ace7559023815966bbbd88af6357374bd511d021aeb9d222f9c08acdbb07ed5
>   App upload arn is :arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:949397191675:upload:cd2fdd09-4c62-42f4-8e27-bde987554d70/22d28644-4c01-4b82-939c-8e39ee5a268e
>     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
>     0 41.2M    0     0    0  400k      0   536k  0:01:18 --:--:--  0:01:18  536k
>    62 41.2M    0     0   62 25.6M      0  14.6M  0:00:02  0:00:01  0:00:01 14.6M
>   100 41.2M    0     0  100 41.2M      0  17.3M  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 17.3M
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   Test upload status : INITIALIZED
>   .
>   .

Comment: Can you show us the commands you executed and their output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a document which shows the process you described

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-test-run.html#how-to-create-test-run-cli-step4

When you have the chance can you let me know if all these steps were followed?

The description suggests to me that the wrong upload url was used or that the upload failed during the curl command.

Please provide full output of the commands in the document and I should be able to help more.

Hth

-James

Comment: Thank you. I've added the code snippet and it's output, and I clearly understood that I was using a different URL to upload the tests.zip.